# How can I export a one page word document into an image of a particular resolution?

Tags: resolution, conversion, image-editing, image-conversion

How can I export a one page word document into an image of a particular resolution?

For example, suppose I have a word document, it has some word art on it, it is one page, it has some pictures, some text

[image]

Now let's say I want to convert that one page into an image with a particular resolution.

I may have other pages that are just text but I also want them converted to the same resolution.  That way I can open an image editor and put them two pics side by side combining them into one pic.  There's no reason why the pics can't be the same size when each of them are one page of a word document.

This is an image of the second doc file

[image]

I want the images in both jpg and png format.

So I have the doc files..

asdf.docx  270KB   http://ge.tt/36MkddW2/v/0

asdflist.docx 12KB  http://ge.tt/771aedW2/v/0

I want to get asdf.jpg asdf.png  asdflist.jpg asdflist.png  i.e. each of those in jpg and in png

same resolution, maintaining aspect ratio.

really I want to be able to choose the resolution. And the aspect ratio should be like a page of a word document.  I want quite a high res like length 3-4K pixels. But any method where I can convert while choosing a resolution would enable me to do that.

I am on MS Office Pro Plus 2013. I tried "paste special" but that didn't include the word art.

Comment: if you are having onenote you may use that to convert the document to image, or else use the snipping tool

Comment: @Rico  you suggest the snipping tool but the snipping tool is definitely no good 'cos it can't scroll down a word document can it? as for onenote, I may have it but I don't know much about its use, can you be more specific re its use as in what to click?

Comment: you may send the document to onenote which will automatically convert all the pages to images

Comment: @Rico I see from what you've said, that you're referring to file..print within word, to onenote..  But that is v limited in terms of resolution. e.g. it offers 600x600 dpi and 1200x1200dpi and no options for  widthxlength in pixels

Comment: I wonder if this can do it.. http://www.doctoimage.com/doc-to-png.html  btw zamzar gives pretty high resolution within the range I mentioned,  and by default, though doesn't let you choose the resolution

Answer (score 0):

If you have Onenote installed in your PC, you may use that

1. Open the Word Document
2. Go to print menu and choose `Send to Onenote` option
3. Then press print
4. The file will be opened in Onenote
5. Now using Onenote save the file as word document
6. Now all the pages in the document are images.
7. You may save them by right-clicking and selecting `Save As Picture`

That's it.

Comment: Please note: Default resolution is 600x600 DPI, You can set this to 1200x1200 in the properties of the "Send to OneNote" printer-driver. If you are going to mess with these in a image-editor, the higher the resolution the better.

Comment: rico, I don't see a save as picture option though I see a save as option http://i.imgur.com/2aBVv6R.png    i'll try to find the resolution setting @Tonny thanks. BTW  in the printer driver option I see DPI(that kind of resolution), but I don't see any number of pixels kind of resolution eg so I can make it 3K pixels across in one dimension.

Comment: Rico, I said I wanted a high res see I wrote "I want quite a high res like length 3-4K pixels "

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed as follow:

- Convert it to pdf, for example with a pdf virtual printer like [CutePDF writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp). Open your file in Word, enter the printing menu and select the CutePDF virtual printer. You can set the output DPI in the advanced printer options Properties->Paper/Quality->Advanced. Keep a high DPI so that at this step you limit the information loss. (Yet, it might be that for too high resolution you might a too big intermediate file, or even that you run out of memory)
- Use an image editor to import it and convert to another image format. [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), for example, allows to choose the resolution when you load a pdf file, see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: just tried converting to pdf with cute pdf writer.  as you wrote "Convert it to pdf, for example with a pdf virtual printer like CutePDF writer".  So I tried installing cute writer,  but it showed this in the start menu http://i.imgur.com/BLC5MMw.png  which links to a webpage web program, which just seems to offer an open file option, but it can't open docx files http://i.imgur.com/e6NBrcF.png

Comment: @barlop It's a virtual printer. You have to open your document in Word, open the printing menu and select the CutePdf printer (there you also control the settings by clicking Properties->Paper/Quality->Advanced)

Comment: I get this message from ms word http://i.imgur.com/3po3paF.png   "there is not enough memory or disk space to repaginate or print this document".  here's my memory profile 16GB RAM http://i.imgur.com/zFu7PN0.png   And hard disk space 47GB

Comment: @barlop Which kind of output DPI did you set? :) Probably you have to find a compromise and lower it a little bit.

Comment: first I tried 4000dpi..got that error, but the max I see to be able to get away with is 1200dpi. (e.g. 2400dpi gets that error),  i'll be trying gimp and update you.

Comment: @barlop Great! I think 1200 dpi it's [beyond what many printers can do](http://www.scantips.com/basics3b.html), it depends then if you have to magnify your document. Out of curiosity, which file size do you get for the pdf with 1200dpi?

Comment: @barlop Did it work in the end?

Answer (score -1):

An easier but not quiet effective way is that you can capture the screen and save it as image. Then combine both images in and image editing software, e.g. Photoshop.